# Terminology - matrix whose elements are the magnitudes of the elements of a complex matrix

Tags: matrices, terminology

Given a complex matrix A, we calculate B whose elements $B_{ij} = |A_{ij}|$. What is B called in terms of A (is there a special name?) and what notation do we use?

Using B = |A| would be problematic since this is the determinant sign.

Comment: I have seen the notation $|A|$, especially in numerical linear algebra. The conflict with the determinant can be avoided by writing $\det A$. The real problem is the symbolic calculus: often, $|A|$ denotes $\sqrt{A^\star A}$.

Comment: Is it called the absolute value of a matrix?

Comment: No. "Matrix of absolute values" is much better.